# How to create a temporary table as copy of another table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I already tried this:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable AS
SELECT * FROM realTable;
```

But then tempTable has only the structure of realTable, but not the elements themselves.

Comment: This *should* populate the table, but you could always do an insert afterwards.

Comment: How can I populate it after I created it?

Comment: `insert into tempTable select * from realtable`.  Of course, column lists are preferable, but that should work.

Comment: That's all very well, but the `create table as` statement should have also populated the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - it did populate the table, but then it disposed of the records,  That's the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> "But then tempTable has only the structure of realTable, but not the
>   elements themselves."

What makes a global temporary table temporary is that the data is transient.  Firstly, the data is only visible within the session which inserts it; any other session will see an empty table.  Secondly, the data can persist for either a transaction or the session, depending on the ON COMMIT clause; the default is ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS.  [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402).

Now the thing is, a DDL statement in Oracle issues two commits, one before and one after the statement in question.  So a DDL statement is a complete, discrete transaction.  Hence this ...

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable AS
SELECT * FROM realTable;
```

... is a transaction and, as it doesn't specify the ON COMMIT clause, it will apply the default which is DELETE ROWS.  So an empty table is the expected behaviour.

The solution is simple: specify the ON COMMIT statement with session-level retention:

```
SQL> select count(*) from t23;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        11

SQL> create global temporary table gtt23
  2  as select * from t23
  3  /

Table created.

SQL> select count(*) from gtt23;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> drop table gtt23;

Table dropped.

SQL> create global temporary table gtt23
  2  on commit preserve rows
  3  as select * from t23
  4  /

Table created.

SQL> select count(*) from gtt23;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        11

SQL>
```

---

Generally, I think that a policy of CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE using SELECT * FROM indicates a misunderstanding of the construct.  GTTs in Oracle are *permanent data structures*; only the records are temporary.  They are not disposable objects like temporary tables in T-SQL.  If that's the sort of thing you want, you should probably be using PL/SQL collections instead. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS005).

Comment: + 1 . . . A very nice explanation.  I do find the default behavior to be counterintuitive, but at least it now makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Global temporary tables can have either transaction-level scope or session-level scope.  The default is to have transaction-level scope which means that the data disappears after the transaction completes.  If you do a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` to create your global temporary table, the data will be inserted but, since `CREATE` is DDL, the data will be removed as soon as the statement completes.

One option would be to create the structure using a query that doesn't return any data

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable AS
  SELECT * 
    FROM realTable
   WHERE 1=0;
```

then insert the data

```
INSERT INTO tempTable
  SELECT *
    FROM realTable;
```

Of course, given how infrequently global temporary tables are used in Oracle (particularly in comparison to other databases), I'd want to be very certain that you really need to create a temporary table from a permanent table in the first place.